# How to buy Ether in the UK?

Tags: ether, exchanges

I would like to buy ether, so I read and google a lot, but still wasn't able to set up my account with buying possibilities.

I registered at CoinBase, identified myself but they didn't charge my bank account (UK) so I can't use that for trading. Sometimes the website forgot that I added my debit card, so I have to do it again.

Anyway, could someone give me a step-by-step 6-year-old tutorial how you bought your first Ethereum? What exchange and bank account have you used, where the bank was located (which country), etc...

I would be very grateful,
Thanks

Comment: The question should be How to buy ether not ethereum. I was surprised looking at the title.